# Azure Certificate import - Bad Parameter

Tags: azure, import, certificate, azure-keyvault

I am creating an azure certificate like this:

```
az keyvault certificate create --name testName -p "$(az keyvault certificate get-default-policy)" --vault-name keyvaulttest01
```

Then I am importing a certificate like this:

```
az keyvault certificate import --file test.pem --name testName --vault-name keyvaultest01
```

After running the import I get following error:

> (BadParameter) The specified PKCS#12 X.509 certificate content can not
> be read. Please check if certificate is in valid PKCS#12 format. Code:
> BadParameter Message: The specified PKCS#12 X.509 certificate content
> can not be read. Please check if certificate is in valid PKCS#12
> format.

My test.pem file has the following format:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
….
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
….
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I thought my test.pem file has a problem, so I tried to upload it manually in the azure ui and it worked.

The strange thing is, after uploading it via the azure ui, suddenly my import command is also working.

So it seems that my pem file is allright, but somehow the azure cli has some problems.
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

**UPDATE:**

After the help of another user, I am using now the following code to import the certificate:

```
policy=$(az keyvault certificate get-default-policy | sed 's$application/x-pkcs12$application/x-pem-file$')
az keyvault certificate import --file test.pem --name testName --vault-name keyvaultest01 --policy $policy
```

Here I am getting now the error:

```
Failed to parse string as JSON:
{
Error detail: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

The policy looks like this:

```
{
  "issuerParameters": {
    "certificateTransparency": null,
    "name": "Self"
  },
  "keyProperties": {
    "curve": null,
    "exportable": true,
    "keySize": 2048,
    "keyType": "RSA",
    "reuseKey": true
  },
  "lifetimeActions": [
    {
      "action": {
        "actionType": "AutoRenew"
      },
      "trigger": {
        "daysBeforeExpiry": 90
      }
    }
  ],
  "secretProperties": {
    "contentType": "application/x-pem-file"
  },
  "x509CertificateProperties": {
    "keyUsage": [
      "cRLSign",
      "dataEncipherment",
      "digitalSignature",
      "keyEncipherment",
      "keyAgreement",
      "keyCertSign"
    ],
    "subject": "CN=CLIGetDefaultPolicy",
    "validityInMonths": 12
  }
}
```

Comment: I also wrote the microsoft support. I will post their answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default certificate policy uses `contentType` `application/x-pkcs12` (PFX). You need `application/x-pem-file` when importing the certificate. There's no need to create the certificate, though: you're creating a second version of the same name when you import. The PEM file should contain both the private and public keys.

```bash
policy=$(az keyvault certificate get-default-policy | sed 's$application/x-pkcs12$application/x-pem-file$')
az keyvault certificate import --file test.pem --name testName --vault-name keyvaultest01 --policy "$policy"
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. I am getting following message when I use your commands:Failed to parse string as JSON:
{
Error detail: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: I added the policy in my problem description.

Comment: The commands I typed worked for me, but it depends on your shell i.e., not an azure CLI problem. Try putting `$policy` in quotes instead like `"$policy"`. I updated my anwer, which is correct (I work on Key Vault).

Comment: thanks, using "$policy" worked for me.